# Google VPN Classic to Fortigate Handshake Errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vpn

I have configured Cloud VPN Classic to on-prem Firewall using Fortigate. I'm using default supported IKE Ciphers and I've confirmed both sides are correct configuration.

But when I checked on Google there errors shown "Handshake with peer broken for unknown reason. Trying again soon"

Does anyone have a suggestion/help on this?

I was troubleshooting these issues almost a month, still didn't find the solution on this case.
I have monitored VPN whole day, I found it will state active/up at certain time, but then it will inactive.

"Handshake with peer broken for unknown reason. Trying again soon"

Answer (score 1):

As there is no information about the specific Fortinet devise you are using in your on-prem network, I'm sharing with you this [Google Cloud VPN interop Guide](https://cloud.google.com/files/CloudVPNGuide-UsingCloudVPNwithFortinetFortiGate300C.pdf) to use Cloud VPN with Fortinet where you should find the correct configuration for GCP connectivity.

Additionally, I have found this [Cloud VPN troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/support/troubleshooting) Google documentation which can help you monitor and solve issues with Cloud VPN.

I hope the provided documentation helps you troubleshoot your issue and to have the expected connectivity results.

Comment: Hi Marcel, Thanks for your suggestion and reference. For your information we are using Fortigate 501E. I will try to follow Fortigate step you shared.